# SUM range of cells after applying a user defined function to each cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have defined a custom function `CalculateProgressionTaxOfSalary` in Google sheets which accepts only one cell and returns its tax.

I want to apply this function to each cell of a range and then sum the results.
Is there any way to do that without changing the function itself? Something like:

```
SUM(CalculateProgressionTaxOfSalary(A2:A10))
```

Comment: Your question is more difficult to answer without an example of your data layout or your function. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your function. Also check out [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Have you tried `SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(CalculateProgressionTaxOfSalary(A2:A10)))`.

Answer (score 0):

> which accepts only one cell

that's your answer. to trick it you would need to do something like:

```
=SUM(CalculateProgressionTaxOfSalary(A2);
     CalculateProgressionTaxOfSalary(A3);
     CalculateProgressionTaxOfSalary(A4);
     CalculateProgressionTaxOfSalary(A5);
     CalculateProgressionTaxOfSalary(A6);
     CalculateProgressionTaxOfSalary(A7);
     CalculateProgressionTaxOfSalary(A8);
     CalculateProgressionTaxOfSalary(A9);
     CalculateProgressionTaxOfSalary(A10))
```